# CPU Spec for AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I hope to evaluate AWS Lambda's suitability for long running computing intensive batch jobs, vs EC2 instances. To do that, I need to find out a 24h cost of Lambda vs EC2 for similar computing power. (In the 24h I'll run many small jobs, each a few seconds)

From [Configuring Lambda function memory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-memory.html) I can see "At 1,769 MB, a function has the equivalent of one vCPU (one vCPU-second of credits per second)". But there is no description of how powerful this CPU will be.

For EC2 nodes, I can find out the CPU specs of T2 or C5 so I know what to expect, but not the case for Lambda. Anyone has an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Lambda can run for max 15 minutes, not 24 hours. Maybe ECS would be better then lambda.

Comment: to clarify, my 24h means many small Lambda jobs running consecutively.

Comment: CPU specs are hard to tell. AWS could change them all the time, because they are not really giving you any guarantees for anything. That's intentional. I would strongly recommend to not use Lambda for your _compute intensive batch jobs_. Furthermore, Lambdas are VMs running on [Firecracker](https://firecracker-microvm.github.io). So which part of the CPUs features is available to the VM, can change as well.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda can run for 15Min only.
AWS doesn't expose lambda compute details. We cannot get the compute details on which lambda is running.

If you have 24 hour task , better to go with EC2 Instances.
If you still want to use lambda which are you may explore stepFunctions.
https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/